# How to find webserver running on server and find why do some web apps respond and some don't?

Tags: linux, centos, web-server, netstat

I didn't configure this server so I don't know what is running or where things are running.  The server is some sort of rack server (1U or 2U Dell running in our datacenter) running Centos.

So we have webapps running on our server.  One is Jenkins on port 8080.  Another is just showing a directory listing of log files in a specific location on the server on port 1234.

We used to be able to access the logs at port 1234 but it stopped working today for some reason.  I don't know what webserver is serving the logs but blindly executing:

```
find / -name "tomcat*"
```

didn't return anything.  I also executed

```
netstat -a | grep 1234
netstat -a | grep 8080
```

but it doesn't show the ports, which doesn't make sense b/c Jenkins is running so at least port 8080 should be returned by netstat (at least I THINK 8080 should return).  Jenkins looks to be running on its own so it doesn't appear to be using tomcat

```
java -jar /path/to/jenkins.war.
```

If anyone could advise me on how to find the webserver running on port 1234, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Did you speak with the server's administrator about any of this?

Comment: @EEAA, the person who is administering this server is on our team but didn't document how this was setup and he's out today.  =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `netstat -a` command might not list all listening ports - try `netstat -tuln | grep 8080` to look for processes listening on port 8080. Next, try simply querying for service status - look in `/etc/init.d/` for files named `tomcat`, `httpd`, or similar, and issue `service $filename status` for each of them. If one or more shows that it's not running, check if it should be running by comparing the output of `who -r` (to get the current runlevel) and `chkconfig --list $filename` (to see what runlevels the given service is "on" for). That should get you started.